# How is my second font not loading?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Suggestions for a change?
https://github.com/Robocop79/Submit/blob/master/Roastedbeef420.html
I tried everything

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by uploading to GitHub directly and here is the code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Kimberley";
    src: url("../Submit/kimberle.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "LemonMilk";
    src: url("../Submit/LemonMilk.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "rc";
    src: url("../Submit/R&C-Demo.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you forgot to close your first `@font-face` with a `}`.

Also, certain font-formats don't always work on the web. Sometimes you'll have to convert them using a [webfont-converter](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Kimberley";
    src: url(http://www.princexml.com/fonts/larabie/kimberle.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "r_c";
    src: url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/p38qag2pb8zwdlq/R%26C-Demo.otf?dl=1) format("otf");
}
```

Comment: nope, and also the first font is gone https://robocop79.github.io/Submit/Roastedbeef420.html <--- make sure you click load unsafe scripts

Comment: still not working, here is the font ---->https://www.dropbox.com/s/p38qag2pb8zwdlq/R%26C-Demo.otf?dl=0

Comment: Updated my answer, try that out and let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Thanks for the first font, the second one still not working|Conversion to true type---->https://www.dropbox.com/s/27sp825za6o0t8w/R%26C-Demo.ttf?dl=0

Comment: I think it is the link that is the problem. I used the font locally as a file and it works: [**see here**](https://i.imgur.com/AeKNwYy.png). I can't seem to find out how or where to upload a webfont for online use.